# Is there a way to test with junit a Wizard that I created?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I have an RCP application on eclipse. At some point, I can open a wizard to create a new specific project (I wrote the code for the wizard). I want to test the creation of the project with junit plugin. My question is, is there a way to "link" the code in the junit class with the events in my RCP application?

Thanks.

Comment: That is too less information. What exact technology did you use to create the wizard? Is this an e4 wizard with an emf model backing it up or maybe just plain SWT with everything handwritten or ...

Comment: I'm using SWT for the widgets and the events and jface for the WizardPage.

Comment: You might want to look at [Eclipse RCPTT](https://eclipse.org/rcptt/)